# How I get Informations of a ListView Item for a Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, listview, webforms

My Situation:

I' ve a ListView, that get Data from the Active Directory. The User input a String (Lastname or a part of this) in a TextBox. Than the ListView list all AD Users with the same string from the TextBox. Every Line get a Button "Anzeigen" to get more Informations about the User. A second WebForm "Benutzer.aspx" display the Information about this User. I think I need a Value (ID or eMail) of the selected User for the second WebForm. So I need a Session. So if I click the Button "Anzeigen" I need the Value of the eMail or ect. of this actually Line in the ListView.

My Problem:

I don't know how I can get the other Informations of this ListView Line. I think I need a kind of Index or I must control a Cell.

My Code:

ASPX

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="UserTable" runat="server" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">
                <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
                    <th id="Th1" runat="server">Benutzer</th>
                    <th id="Th2" runat="server">eMail</th>
                    <th id="Th3" runat="server">Vorname</th>
                    <th id="Th4" runat="server">Nachname</th>
                    <th id="Th5" runat="server">Telefon</th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>

            <tr runat="server"> 

                <td align="left" ><asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzer") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Label ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefon") %>' runat="server" /></td>
                <td align="left"><asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Anzeigen" OnCommand="Button1_Command" CommandName="Anzeigen" CommandArgument="myArgument" runat="server" /></td>

            </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
```

CS

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Anzeigen")
            {
              //Here I need a Session and the Informations about the Selected User in the Line

                Response.Redirect("Benutzer.aspx");

            }
    }
```

tarasov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I unerstand correctly, you need a reference to Label which shows the email in the list view. For this first get a reference, see the below code:

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Anzeigen")
        {
          //Here I need a Session and the Informations about the Selected User in the Line
            Label lb = (Label) myListView.Items(1).FindControl("Label2"); // give the right index, Label2 contains the email so give its ID but index should be correct
            string email = lb.Text;
            Response.Redirect("Benutzer.aspx");

        }
}
```

Comment: Label l = (Label)myListView.Items[1].FindControl("Label2");

Comment: Label lb = (Label) myListView.Items(1).FindControl("Label2"); // ..Items(1) is wrong in my code ...and [1] is right ...why? ^^

Comment: @Tarasov you are using C# or VB ? if C# then it should be  Items[1] if VB then Items(1)

Comment: ah ok ... sry for my stupid question :D I use C# ...you're right, thanks! ...I can test it on monday because I don't have the Active Directory Database at home :P

Comment: @Tarasov create an myListView_SelectedIndexChanging event, you can get the selected index from this event.

Comment: I look on msdn...but I dont't know how I can do it :(

Comment: here is an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindexchanging.aspx

Comment: if I Use protected void Button1_Command(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {}